# Access values for a dictionary within a list in a column of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a pandas dataframe, where each row is a list with a dictionary inside, like this:

```
urls
---------------------------------------------------------
[{'url': http://t.co, 'expanded_url':http://nytimes.com}]
[{'url': http://t.co, 'expanded_url':http://time.com}] 
[]
```

Some of the rows only have an empty list. 
So I'm trying to extract the value of just the expanded_url, and when I test the following function on a test list, I'm able to do that:

```
test_list = [{'url': 'https://t.co', 'expanded_url': 'https://nytimes.com'}]

def get_expanded_url(outterlist):
    for item in outterlist:
        if isinstance(item, dict):
            return item['expanded_url']
        else:
            return None
```

However when I apply this to a column in the dataframe like this:

```
df.urls.apply(lambda x: get_expanded_url(x))
```

I only get NaNs, even where I shouldn't (where there isn't just an empty list). First of all can someone explain why my function doesn't work on the dataframe? And secondly, how can I extract just the values for expand_url from the column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def get_expanded_url(outterlist):
    try:
        return outterlist[0]['expanded_url']
    except IndexError:
        return None

df.urls.apply(get_expanded_url)
```

The function will try to obtain the url that you want. If it can't, it will return `None`.

Also, when using `apply`, you can give only the name of the function. It is not required to create the lambda function.